# ¿Como envio un Array desde un Componente hijo al padre? React JS

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, react-hooks, component

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el componente Inputs.jsx tengo un arreglo y lo necesito leer en App.js ¿Como puedo enviar esos datos desde el elemento hijo (Inputs.js) al padre (App.js)? Gracias, de antemano

Tengo la siguiente ruta como se muestra en la imagen

> 

```
|--Components  
  |-Inputs.jsx (Aqui estan los datos)
  |-Menu.jsx
  |-Post.jsx
|--App.js (Aqui los necesito leer)
```

...

Comment: Si pudieras agregar código, Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar un estado global, con librerias como redux, o usando contexto, [Ejemplo contexto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442312/como-mostrar-ocultar-un-componente-desde-otro-componente-en-reactjs/442323#442323), Pero algo mas sencillo para este caso seria algo asi, en el componente padre:

```
import React from 'react';
export default const App = () => {
    const [estado, setEstado] = useEstate()
    return(
        <Input estado={estado} setEstado={setEstado} />
    );
}
```

En el padre le estas pasando el estado, y la funcion para cambiar el estado, entonces supongo que en el input vas a cambiar el estado, por lo tanto esto afectaria el estado en app, y podrias usarlo:

en el componente hijo:

```
import React from 'react';
export default const Input = (props) => {
    return(
        <p>Input text</p>
        <input type="text" value={estado} onChange={(e)=>setEstado(e.target.value)} />
    );
}
```