# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un componente React hijo a una función padre?

Tags: reactjs, api, component

Estoy realizando la sección de comentarios de una plataforma web de tal manera que cada comentario aporta, a parte de un nombre y un contenido, una calificación en estrellas que el creador del comentario aporta. Como si fuera el comentario de una app de Google Play, para que nos entendamos.

Entonces tengo la siguiente función:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {RatingSlider} from "./RatingSlider";
import Comentarios from "./Comentarios";

const ListOfComments = () => {

    const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(false)
    const [showRate, setRate] = useState(false)

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <RatingSlider showAllCallback={(response) => setShowAll(response)} rate={showRate}/>
            <div className="center">
                <div id="content">
                    <Comentarios showAllCallback={(response) => setRate(response)} ncomments={showAll}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );

}

export default ListOfComments;
```

Verán que tengo dos fragmento, `ratingSlider` y un div que contiene `Comentarios` y que, de hecho, `ratingSlider` le pasa con un callback datos a `Comentarios`. Pero para hacer eso hice que `ratingSlider` fuera también una función:

```
import React from "react";
import {useTranslation} from "react-i18next";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import StarRatings from 'react-star-ratings';


export const RatingSlider = ({showAllCallback}) => {
    const [t] = useTranslation("global")
    return (
        <div id="slider">
            <div className="sliderContent">
                <div className="rating">
                    <StarRatings
                        rating={3.1}
                        starRatedColor="#FCCF00"
                        numberOfStars={5}
                        starDimension="100px"
                    />
                </div>

                /*CODIGO IRRELEVANTE*/
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Verán que dentro de ratingSlider tengo un componente StarRating (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-star-rating) que quería que mostrara la **media de todas las puntuaciones de todos los comentarios** y que, por el momento, tengo hardcodeado con un 3.1.

Me gustaría aprovechar la llamada que hago a la API en el componente `Comentarios` y enviarle la media que he calculado para ponerla en ratingSlider pero uso métodos como `ComponentWillMount()` o `ComponentWillUpdate()` que me impiden transformarlo en una función como hice con `ratingSlider`.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';
import Global from "../Global";
import StarRatings from "react-star-ratings";

var averageRate = [];

class Comentarios extends Component {
    url = Global.url;
    state = {
        comments: [],
        rate: 0,
        status: null
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        this.getComments(this.props.ncomments);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (prevProps && prevProps.ncomments !== this.props.ncomments)
            this.getComments(this.props.ncomments);

    }

    getComments = (all) => {
        if (all) {
            axios.get(this.url + "/comments").then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    comments: res.data.comments,
                    status: 'success'
                });
            });
        } else {
            axios.get(this.url + "/comments/last").then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    comments: res.data.comments,
                    status: 'success'
                });
            });
        }
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.comments.length >= 1) {

            var listComments = this.state.comments.map((c) => {
                {
                    averageRate.push(c.rate)
                }
                return (
                    <div key={c._id} id="comentarios">
                        <h1>{c.name}</h1>
                        <div className="commentStar">
                            <StarRatings
                                rating={c.rate}
                                starRatedColor="#FCCF00"
                                numberOfStars={5}
                                starDimension="30px"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearfix"/>
                        <h3>{c.content}</h3>
                        <span className="date"> <Moment locale="es" fromNow>{c.date}</Moment></span>
                    </div>
                );
            });
/*AQUI ESTA EL DATO QUE QUIERO ENVIAR AL COMPONENTE PADRE PARA ENVIARLO AL OTRO HIJO*/
            console.log("exacto: " + averageRate.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / averageRate.length);

            return (
                <div>
                    {listComments}
                </div>
            );

        } else if (this.state.comments.length === 0 && this.state.status === 'success') {
            return (
                <div id="comentarios">
                    <h1>No hay comentarios para mostrar</h1>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div id="comentarios">
                    <h1>Cargando...</h1>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Comentarios;
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para pasarle ese valor al padre para que se lo pase al otro hijo (o sea indirectamente un cambio entre hermanos). Espero haberme explicado, saludos!

Comment: Entonces ¿Quieres pasar el valor de la `media` del componente `Comentarios` al componente `RatingSlider`? Saludos

Comment: Tal vez te ayude esto, al parecer duplicado [#67027728](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442312/como-mostrar-ocultar-un-componente-desde-otro-componente-en-reactjs/442323#442323), o tal vez [#442872](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442837/como-envio-un-array-desde-un-componente-hijo-al-padre-react-js/442872#442872)